# push back an array of struct by initialization list or variable

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, stdvector

I have a weird problem on initialization of my struct. I guess it is an coding error but it leads to an internal segmentation fault of the compiler.
my gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) (sry can't change that)
I compile with -std=c++0x

My struct look likes:

```
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
} coordinate_t;
```

my configuration object has a member
`std::vector< coordinate_t[2] > wall_coord;`

and I want to add a entrance to the vector by

```
this->wall_coord.push_back({ coordinate_t{0,2}, coordinate_t{0,6} });
```

I also tried

```
this->wall_coord.push_back(coordinate_t[2]{ {0,2}, {0,6} });
```

but that lead to a bunch of errors, so I thougt, hang on, take the long way:

```
coordinate_t coord[2]={ coordinate_t{0,2}, coordinate_t{2,0} };
this->wall_coord.push_back( coord );
```

but, bam, just another bunch of errors. I understood that he has problems by allocating the storage or something like this.
I read several articles about push_back, but I don't get the clue behind that.
Hopefully you have an idea.

---

Ahh you want some errormsg i guess?
I put them in a pastebin (hope that is okay)
http://pastebin.com/ZaJ5wV8Y

Comment: _"I put them in a pastebin (hope that is okay)"_ No it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store raw C arrays in a std container.  Arrays do not behave enough like regular values with their inability to be returned from functions, and their tendency to decay to pointers, etc.

Use `std::array<coordinate_t,2>` which behaves more like a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrape your struct in a class, then assgin your coordinates to the class constructor.

```
#include <vector>


class WallCoordinates{

struct{int y,x;} coord[2];

public:

  WallCoordinates(int _y1 = 0, int _x1 = 0,int _y2 = 0, int _x2 = 0){

    coord[0].y = _y1 ;
    coord[0].x = _x1 ;
    coord[1].y = _y2 ; 
    coord[1].x = _x2 ; 
      }

};


std::vector<WallCoordinates> wall_coord ;

int main () {
  wall_coord.push_back(WallCoordinates(1,2,3,4)) ;
}
```